# Need to change variable after initializing library

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I need give value for varrible after pressed button :

```js
$('#show-more').click(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    scrollOverflow: false
   })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show-more"> show more </button>
```

Comment: Not clear, ask properly

Answer (score 0):

**You can not.**

Nothing [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) indicates that's possibility. Why do you think you can?

There's also [an open issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/958) about it on github.